# Ubuntu custom URL protocol handler

Tags: linux, url, ubuntu, protocols, handler

I want to ask a question, but I will first show my files

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="cloudje:firefox">Open firefox</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c gedit
Name[en_US]=Gedit
Comment[en_US]=Small, easy-to-use program to access iTunesU media
Name=TunesViewer
Comment=Small, easy-to-use program to access iTunesU media
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/tunesview.svg
Categories=Application;Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/cloudje;
Comment[en_US.utf8]=Small, easy-to-use program to access iTunesU media
```

Tutorial: [http://jarrpa.net/2011/10/28/creating-custom-url-handlers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10-gnome-3-0/](https://web.archive.org/web/20121223075509/http://jarrpa.net/2011/10/28/creating-custom-url-handlers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10-gnome-3-0/)

Ok, this is cool. The .desktop file will be placed in /usr/share/applications. If you execute the command 'xdg-open cloudje:firefox' or something like 'xdg-open cloudje:example', it will always execute gedit using a Python script named 'cloudjerun'. How can I execute firefox using the command 'xdg-open cloudje:firefox'?

Do I need to replace 'Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c gedit' to 'Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c %U' or 'Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c %s' or something?

Comment: The Tutorial link is no more working.

Answer (score 6):

In a desktop file [following parameters](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en#tb-exec-params) are possible for Exec

```
Add...  Accepts...
%f      a single filename.
%F      multiple filenames.
%u      a single URL.
%U      multiple URLs.
%d      a single directory. Used in conjunction with %f to locate a file.
%D      multiple directories. Used in conjunction with %F to locate files.
%n      a single filename without a path.
%N      multiple filenames without paths.
%k      a URI or local filename of the location of the desktop file.
%v      the name of the Device entry.
```

So in your case you can adjust your Exec entry as you described to the following:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/cloudjerun -c %u
```

Note though that %u is the complete uri so e.g. when you run **xdg-open cloudje:firefox** %u will be **cloudje:firefox**. Easiest I assume is to adjust the cloudjerun python script removing the first part of the uri before running it.

Comment: If I was still working at the company I made this for, you would be helping me a lot! WebSockets were my solution!

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://github.com/LinuxCrafts/Custom-Protocol-handler-creator) might help
(its a program for creating custom protocol handlers easily)
(you will need to install kde-apps or kde-full and then run this, you will also need to run this in a **Terminal**.
Also you **MUST** run it as **root**(`sudo ~/Downloads/ProtocolCreator.sh`))
it will create a folder with the protocol handler name(like the https in https:) in your home directory. use `$1` for getting the full url. there is no easy way to make it just be the part after `[something]:` ...
modify the file inside that folder to make it contain all you need
now with that said if you want to open firefox, use `<a href="blablabla:firefox">Open Firefox</a>` while the file in the folder has the content:
`#!/bin/bash`
`firefox`
now when the link is clicked, Firefox should open!